# condition to use method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying method of undetermined coefficients and i can understant what is its idea.

But i'm ambiguous when we can use it.

Of course, it is obvious that the differential equation is nonhomogeneous. And wikipidia says as following:

---

Undetermined coefficients is not as general a method as variation of parameters, since it
only works for differential equations that follow certain forms.

---

But my book or wikipidia don't say the equation need to be linear or non linear

To apply the method of undetermined coefficients, the differential equation have to be linear? or non-linear or both?

Comment: @Moo I'm sorry but is there any answer for my question?

Comment: @Moo does it say equation need to be linear or non-linear?